# If there is no value display default date - date-picker - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am finding my way out with the `react-datepicker` , and everything runs smoothly until i delete the input date filed it throws me an error : `index.js:372 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value` . I get it proabally the error comes from there because there is no a default date in use . So my question is how can i fix that . Here is an example of my code :

```
this.state= {
            startDate: moment().startOf('day').subtract(20, 'days'),
            endDate: moment().startOf('day').add(1,'days'),
}

   handleStartDate = date => {

        this.setState({
            startDate: moment(date).startOf('day')
        }, () => {
            if (moment(date).startOf('day').isAfter(this.state.endDate)) {
                this.setState({
                    endDate: moment(date).startOf('day').add(1,'days')
                })
            }
        });
    }

    handleEndDate = date => {
        this.setState({
            endDate: moment(date).startOf('day').add(1,'days')
        });
    };

...
 return (
      <DatePicker
          id='startDate'
          dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          defaultValue = {this.startDate}
          selected={this.state.startDate.toDate()}
          onChange={this.handleStartDate}
       />

      <DatePicker
          id='endDate'
          dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          minDate={this.state.startDate.toDate()}
          selected={this.state.endDate.toDate()}
          onChange={this.handleEndDate}
       />

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not actually a default value issue, you just need to check if that passed `argument` from `onChange` method is holding some values.

```js
handleStartDate = date => {
  // When you delete the input value "date" will return null
  // So if no values, just do nothing
  if (!date) return

  //...

}
```

And same goes for `handleEndDate`

[image: Edit react-datepicker-start-end-example]

---

Also, if you are trying to do some Date Picker **Range** I guess you might find [@y0c/react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@y0c/react-datepicker) more useful. Here is an [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pw6n17pk57) example

Comment: indeed that was the issue . Cheers mate thanks for the help . I will look around for the npm package that you have send me . Maybe i will give it a try !